# If $P(x)=x^4+a_0 x^3+a_1 x^2+a_2 x+a_3$, $P(x)>0$, and $Q(x)=a_3x^4+a_2 x^3+a_1x^2+a_0 x$ prove that $Q(a_3)>-2$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials

> Given: 
>   $$P(x)=x^4+a_0 x^3+a_1 x^2+a_2 x+a_3, P(x)>0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$$ $$\text{and}~~Q(x)=a_3x^4+a_2 x^3+a_1x^2+a_0 x$$
>   Prove or disprove: $Q(a_3)>-2$.

This is a question from a math contest. Working on the problem, using the assumptions, it is easy to see that
$$Q(a_3)=a_3(a_3^4+a_2 a_3^2+a_1a_3+a_0)$$
and,

$$(a)~a_3>0,~~~(b)~1+a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3>0,~~~(c)~1-a_0+a_1-a_2+a_3>0$$
so that adding the inequalities (b) and (c) we find 
$$a_1+a_3>-1$$
I think that I'm close to untie the knot but I feel that I'm missing something.

Hints and solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you observe carefully, you'll see that $${\rm P}(x)=x^4+a_0 x^3+a_1 x^2+a_2 x+a_3$$ $${\rm P}\left( \frac 1x \right)=\frac{a_3x^4+a_2 x^3+a_1x^2+a_0 x+1}{x^4}$$

$$\implies {\rm P}\left( \frac 1x \right)=\frac{{\rm Q}(x)+1}{x^4}$$

$${\rm Q}(x)=x^4 {\rm P}\left( \frac 1x \right) - 1$$

Now we have ${\rm P}(x) >0 \; \forall x  \implies {\rm P}(0) >0 \implies \color{blue}{a_3 >0}$

and ${\rm P}\left(\dfrac 1{a_3}\right) >0$.

Therefore we have $$a_3^4 \; \cdot{\rm P}\left(\frac 1{a_3}\right) >0 \implies a_3^4 \; \cdot{\rm P}\left(\frac 1{a_3}\right)-1= \color{red}{{\rm Q}(a_3) >-1}$$

Thus ${\rm Q}(a_3)>-2$

Comment: $Q(a_3)>0$ at the end?

Comment: @GNUSupporter No, $Q(a_3)>-2$ as asked in question.

Comment: Congrats on 15k bro! ^_^

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry I confused myself.  So +1 for proving something stronger than required.

Comment: @GNUSupporter No problem :)

Comment: Thanks and congrats! I think your result is indeed more general...$\forall x\ne 0$ as $P(1/x)>0$, we have $x^4 P(1/x)>0$,  but as you´ve showed, $x^4 P(1/x)=1+Q(x)$ therefore,  $1+Q(x)>0$ and $Q(x)>-1$, $\forall x\ne 0$. The corollary is $Q(a_3)>-1$, as $a_3\ne 0$.

Comment: @bluemaster Welcome :)